Finding the underlying hexagonal grid and a solution for the distortion field that fit this sparse, noisy, distorted sampling
I have some surface scanning data that yields a low density of spot positions that lie approximately on a regular hexagonal grid.
Deviations from a regular grid come from a small x/y scaling difference as well as not-exact orthogonality, as well as slow variations in the magnitude of those effects across the field and a little random, uncorrelated noise.
I'd like to find a way to recover the regular hexagonal grid and a solution for the distortion field that maps it to the measured points.
I can think of a few kinds of approaches;

some kind of Monte-Carlo jiggling balls dropping in and filling up the space
some kind of numerical solution that maps the points to Eisenstein integers either a minimization or matrix inversion
dumb search of all kinds of distorted grids starting with a best guess

combined with a low order polynomial for the distortions and their variation.
But before I dive in, I'd like to find out if there is a preferred or even an established method to do this.
I'm asking for advice, not the solution. But, just in case someone would like to play with some coordinates, here is generator of simulated data:
The small black dots are a regular hexagonal lattice, and the large gray dots are an example of the type of data I need to analyze.
Here the lattice parameter, rotation, and sampling fraction are
a = 1.23
R = 17   # degrees
f = 0.2

and a distortion field is generated with
xx = x + 0.1 * np.cos(x/3) + 0.02 * y - 0.2
yy = y + y**3 / 40000 - 0.2

where 0 < x, y < 35
For the lower part (y ≲ 20) the deviation from the grid is small. The data becomes more challenging in the upper part where (because of the cubic term in this case) some spots have "drifted" closer to an adjacent lattice point.
This is why just direct fitting of a grid won't work for me - the distortion needs to be fitted at the same time.
This suggests to me that starting by fitting a small patch, then slowly expanding it and refitting both the grid and the distortion after each step might be a good way to go.

Here's the script for that plot:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def hex_grid(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, a=1, R=0, f=0.5):
    uvecs = np.array([[1, 0], [0.5, 3**0.5/2]])
    s, c = [f(np.radians(R)) for f in (np.sin, np.cos)]
    rot = np.array([[c, s], [-s, c]])
    vecs = a * (uvecs[..., None] * rot).sum(axis=1)
    center = 0.5 * np.array([xmin + xmax, ymin + ymax])
    hw = 0.5 * max([xmax - xmin, ymax - ymin])
    nmax = int(1.5 * hw / a) + 1 # overfill
    ij = np.mgrid[-nmax:nmax+1, -nmax:nmax+1].reshape(2, -1)
    xy = (vecs[..., None] * ij[:, None]).sum(axis=0) + center[:, None]
    keep = ((xy[0] > xmin) * (xy[0] < xmax) *
            (xy[1] > ymin) * (xy[1] < ymax))
    xy = xy[:, keep]
    return xy

def random_sample(xy, f=0.5):
    keep = np.random.random(xy.shape[1]) < f
    xy_sampled = xy[:, keep].copy()
    return xy_sampled

a = 1.23
R = 17   # degrees
f = 0.2

np.random.seed(42)

xmin, xmax = 0, 35
ymin, ymax = 0, 35

xy_grid = hex_grid(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, a=a, R=R, f=f)

x, y = random_sample(xy_grid, f=f)

xx = x + 0.1 * np.cos(x/3) + 0.02 * y - 0.2
yy = y + y**3 / 40000 - 0.2

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.plot(*xy_grid, '.k', ms=4)
ax.plot(xx, yy, 'o', c=[0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.4], ms=6)
ax.set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()


If the boundary of the original hexagonal mesh is not defined, there is no unique solution to the problem. Can we, at least, assume that the boundary of the point cloud is predefined somehow, e.g., via convex-hull or alpha-shape algorithms? Moreover, can we assume a unique element type?

@ConvexHull yes, as I mention, for my problem this is "surface scanning data" and so is quite bounded. The machine's scanning area is rectangular. But there is noise near the edges because these points are centers of "blobs" and come from a maxima-finding algorithm and blobs near the edge are truncated. So a "walking" method should start somewhere inside and work its way out. And the points really do fall on a nearly-hexagonal grid the same way Eisenstein integers do, except for the imperfections outlined in the question.

Can you add an example with the original mesh. The element types are six-sided polygons or quadrilaterals in two dimensions?

@ConvexHull done!

Grow your grid from the middle.
A regular 2D grid can be constructed by two vectors $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ via (see e.g. these 2D lattice vectors):
$$ P_{ij} \approx n_i \vec{a} + n_j \vec{b}$$
In your case these might be one pointing up- and slightly right and one pointing to the upper left (or their respective inverses). If you find the approximate vectors, you have a very good guess of where your next gridpoint will be starting from any one point in your grid.
What you could do is choose a point in the middle, search for the fitting four adjacent points via the two approximate vectors and create a new cell. Here the tuples for $n_i$ and $n_j$ would be: $(1,0), (0,1),(1,1)$ when constructing an adjacent cell. Since you always search via local offset and not via a global grid search, you should get robust(ish) results.

I'll give it a try this weekend, thanks! I can imagine two very different approaches that match this advice. One is an expanding circle, after the radius is incremented slighlty, the coefficients of the distortion field polynomial will still be close and the re-minimization will be quick. Another is to ignore any global distortion field during the "grow" stage and just build a big collection of local vectors that fit locally. Once that process spans the space, go back and find a distortion field that best fits the variation in local vectors.

Were you thinking of either one of those in particular, or something else instead, or leaving the specifics as an exercise for the reader?

i was just thinking about finding the grid. Calculating the distortion field should be a second step.
